# Error ASP.NET en modelo

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

He creado un proyecto de ASP.NET y he intregrado un modelo de datos basado en la base de datos sobre la que voy a trabajar :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las relaciones que están establecidas se han hecho de forma manual, ya que no se implementaron de forma automática, y por lo tanto en mis archivos .cs correspondientes no aparecían los siguientes fragmentos de código que posteriormente, después de establecerlas se generaron automáticamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El principal problema es que después de todo este proceso, me han aparecido una serie de fallos en mi proyecto que no soy capaz de solucionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier artículo, información o opinión sería de gran ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Parece bastante claro tu error, no has hecho ninguna asignacion, has creado algun objeto `JuegoPlataforma`? `JuegoPlataforma juego = new JuegoPlataforma(){//elementos}`

Comment: Por ahora no he instanciado objetos, es un ejemplo académico. ¿Dónde debería realizar esas asignaciones de forma correcta?

Comment: Según lo que veo, estás iniciando con ASP.net MVC, este workshop te será de ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Answer (score 0):

Pues, aunque la forma correcta de hacerlo es crear los modelos, luego las migraciones y actualizar la base de datos ... para evitar problemas a futuro.

La solucion más rápida a su problema es crear las migraciones, entrar al archivo de migraciones y comentar el codigo para que al hacer la actualización de la base de datos no se ejecute la creacion de tablas o la modificacion de campos y finalmente correr database-update para que quede sincronizado la base de datos y el proyecto MVC:

Ejemplo:

- Paso1 Eliminar cualquier error en el codigo (la app debe compilar sin errores)
- Paso2 crea la migración: Add-Migration update
- Paso3 edita el archivo generado y comenta las acciones:

```
namespace MEE.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class update: DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            //CreateTable(
            //    "dbo.Profiles",
            //    c => new
            //        {
            //            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            //            Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
            //            Description = c.String(maxLength: 255),
            //            UrlIcon = c.String(),
            //            Color = c.String(),
            //            UrlDocument = c.String(),
            //        })
            //    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            //DropTable("dbo.Profiles");
        }
    }
}
```

- Paso4 corre actualizacion: Update-Database

y listo ... con estos pasos queda sincronizada la base de datos con el proyecto y no volvera a salir el error que comentas.

Comment: ¿Estos pasos lo podría aplicar a un proyecto de ASP.NET MVC sin problema alguno?

Comment: Cuando realizo la migración, no me aparece el código que he de comentar y además no se eliminan todos los errores.

Comment: Como primera medida .. debes elimnar los mensajes de error, la app debe compilar sin problemas. Despues generas la migracion .. el IDE debe abrir el nuevo archivo de migración .. si no lo habre automaticamente, debes mirar en la carpeta "migrations" .. hay un archivo con el nombre que le indicate en el comando de add-migration y ese archivo es donde debes comentar para por ultimo actualizar la base de datos.